# Search with key on multitple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to count the presence of people for each week on a particular event.

Each sheet of my excel workbook has a date as a name, which is when the event took place.
The organisation of each sheet is always the same, one row equals one value, each name is always on the same line.

How can I count number of times each person showed up at the event ?

I can't use a macro. I'm open to other logical way to name the sheets, but the date must always be present.

```
Example :

   Sheet 1 named "03-01-16" :

              A        B

      1   John Doe     X
      2   Mike Dough   X

   Sheet 2 named "10-01-16" :

              A        B

      1   John Doe     NO
      2   Mike Dough   X


Both John Doe and Mike Dough were here on January, 1rst.
Only Mike Dough was here on January, 10th.
```

---

```
Failed Tries so far :

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT('09-04-16'!C2);TRUE))
- Gives "#REF" error for one sheet
- Can't generalize to other sheets
```

Comment: Nobody here is skilled enough to know how to do this ?

Comment: No, there are *plenty* of users here that can accomplish that. However, superuser *isn't* a scripting service. Please review [what makes a question good](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You added your formula attempt a mere 30 minutes ago, so anyone that looked at this earlier would probably skip right over it.

Comment: Additionally a pivot table might be your answer. You also might just have to restructure the data.